# Instagram Graph API: Convert ig_id to id - Migrating from Instagram API => Graph API

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to migrate a custom reporting platform from Instagram's old API to the new Graph API ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata )

I have a database that has stored a few years worth of post data for reporting purposes and it holds the id of the post in the old format of `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyy`.

The new Graph API returns two IDs `id` and `ig_id`. The `ig_id` relates to the x part of the original ID above. The new Graph API doesn't allow you to query media by the `ig_id`, only the id, so my question is - is there a way to convert the `ig_id` to the `id` or retrieve the `id` from the `ig_id`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a direct method to go from the old id to the new id.  The way I have done it is to get the full list of media and then iterate through that to match the old id.  I think you already know this, but I'm going to write this out in case someone else finds this post and wants more details.

If you go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#6--get-the-instagram-business-account-s-media-objects), step 6, you will see the endpoint to retrieve all media objects for the specified business account.  The url is:

https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/business-id-here/media?access_token=access-token-here

This will return a list of ids for the new graph api.

At this point, you will need to pull the detailed information for each media object.  The documentation is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media).  The end point is:

https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/media-id-here?access_token=access-token-here&fields=caption,children,comments,id,ig_id,media_type,media_url,owner,permalink,shortcode,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username

This will give you both the old id and the new id, which can be matched.

Comment: Facebook has made everything related to Instagram apis a real piece of $#%@!!!

Comment: couldn't agree more